# removeClass jquery statement not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery statement and it is adding the class 'current' but it is not removing the class form the siblings.

Any ideas why?

```
$('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num + ']')
  .addClass('current').siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
```

Malcolm

Comment: Do you have sample HTML for this? Did you make sure `siblings()` captures what you want?

Comment: This is a markup issue. Replicating your example above, and using the markup that it seems you're attempting to apply this snippet to, I was able to get it working, which means that it's not a problem with your JavaScript/jQuery logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your HTML markup, I'm guessing your classes aren't direct siblings but wrapped in something (to give them a border maybe?) In that case, `.siblings()` isn't finding anything.

In any case, it might be simpler to just remove `current` from all `class="page_link"` elements without caring where they are, like this:

```
$(".page_link.current").removeClass('current');
$('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num + ']').addClass('current');
```

Comment: thank's, I'm still perplexed as to why if I have this wouldn't work?

    $(".currentmenuItem").removeClass("currentMenuItem");

I had to do this

    $("#mainMenu .currentmenuItem").removeClass("currentMenuItem");

Comment: @vvMINOvv - classes are case sensitive, the `M` in `Menu` differs in your first line :)