# Jquery removeClass not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm designing a javascript function to highlight a label in a scrollable list and scroll to it; highlighting and scrolling is ok.

Problem is I also whant to "de-highlight" previously highighted labels if there are any (for future searches). To highlight I add a css class, to de-highlight I use removeClass from jQuery to remove the css class if it exists; but it doesn't work, for some reason. This is my function:

```
$('.targetUserName').each(function () {
    index++;          
    s = this.innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase().match(regex);
    if(s != null) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'current');
        foundUsers++;

        if (foundUsers == 1 && index > 10)
            $('#usersDiv').scrollTop(index * height);

    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('current'))
        $(this).removeClass('current'); //this is not working

});
```

Comment: Check your $(this) to make sure it is the this you are actually looking for.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  Also: there's no need to call `.toString()` on the value of `innerHTML`; it's always a string already. Use `.addClass()` to add a class. Declare local variables with `var`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482753/removeclass-jquery-statement-not-working

Comment: Is the `else if` condition matched? Does it enter the `else if` part? Try adding an alert to see if it does.

Comment: Can you share the HTML for the list.

Comment: @Harry you are right, it was never entering all along, I added the answer with the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I simply had a bug: I attributed all of these labels a class (targetUserName) to identify them using jQuery, which was being erased when I was highlighting the labels, because I used 
.attr('class', 'current') to set the class, which was erasing the old class. This caused these items not to be taken into consideration in the each() function, thus the previously added 'current'  class never got to be removed. I corrected the code to use addClass() instead of attr('class') and now it works fine.

```
 $('.targetUserName').each(function () {
    index++;
    s = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().match(regex);
    if (s != null) {
        //$(this).attr('class', 'current') // this was the mistake
        $(this).addClass('current'); //correct
        foundUsers++;
        if (foundUsers == 1 && index > 10)
            $('#usersDiv').scrollTop(index * height);

    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('current'))
        $(this).removeClass('current');

});
```